# Add Google map programmatically to Relative layout

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to add Google Map at runtime to a particular layout.

```
mMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(android.R.id.content, mMapFragment, MAP_FRAGMENT_TAG);
mainLayout.addView(mMapFragment);
```

At the time of adding **mainLayout.addView(mMapFragment)** it shows null pointer error.

Errors

```
(19:34) amitsharma.cssoft: 09-30 19:23:40.457: E/AndroidRuntime(16595): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-30 19:23:40.457: E/AndroidRuntime(16595): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-30 19:23:40.457: E/AndroidRuntime(16595):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1821)
09-30 19:23:40.457: E/AndroidRuntime(16595):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1808)
09-30 19:23:40.457: E/AndroidRuntime(16595):    at com.example.project_katchup.Settings.ShowCurrentLocation(Settings.java:222)
09-30 19:23:40.457: E/AndroidRuntime(16595):    at com.example.project_katchup.Settings.access$0(Settings.java:211)
09-30 19:23:40.457: E/AndroidRuntime(16595):    at com.example.project_katchup.Settings$1.onClick(Settings.java:151)
09-30 19:23:40.457: E/AndroidRuntime(16595):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
09-30 19:23:40.457: E/AndroidRuntime(16595):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
09-30 19:23:40.457: E/AndroidRuntime(16595):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-30 19:23:40.457: E/AndroidRuntime(16595):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-30 19:23:40.457: E/AndroidRuntime(16595):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
09-30 19:23:40.457: E/AndroidRuntime(16595):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
09-30 19:23:40.457: E/AndroidRuntime(16595):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-30 19:23:40.457: E/AndroidRuntime(16595):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-30 19:23:40.457: E/AndroidRuntime(16595):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
09-30 19:23:40.457: E/AndroidRuntime(16595):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
09-30 19:23:40.457: E/AndroidRuntime(16595):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-30 19:28:46.757: I/Process(16595): Sending signal. PID: 16595 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Add the error you obtain. It could help.

Comment: please check i have uploaded the errors

Answer (score 0):

**Remove the line**

```
mainLayout.addView(mMapFragment);
```

In your relative layout that you call **mainLayout**, you should have a FrameLayout called android.R.id.content. Maybe something like this:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@android:id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Or: use `android:id="@+id/container_map"` and replace `android.R.id.content` with `R.id.container_map`

---

Without xml:

**Remove the line**

```
mainLayout.addView(mMapFragment);
```

At the beginning:

```
mainLayout.setId(R.id.container_map);
```

Replace `android.R.id.content` with `R.id.container_map`

Create file ids.xml in res/values

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="container_map" type="id" />
</resources>
```

Comment: I have done this But i am also want XML FrameLayout by programing

Comment: I dont want to use xml